# Why Circle is traced counterclockwise and ellipse is traced clock wise?

Tags: circles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

In the [Lecture 32: Polar Coordinates](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/lecture-32-polar-coordinates/),professor traces the circle counterclockwise, but traces the ellipse clockwise.

> "Which was this one here. And first we noted that this does parameterize, as we say, the circle. That satisfies the equation for the circle. And it's traced **counterclockwise**."
>
> "So this is what happens at $ t = 0 $. This is where we are at $ t = \frac{\pi}{2} $. And it continues all the way around, etc. To the rest of the ellipse. This is the direction. So this one happens to be **clockwise**."

What is the principle behind choosing the direction of tracing the curves?

Comment: It might not be a principle, but sometimes the parametrization is required to be traced counterclockwise in order to perform some integrals. For example, Stoke's Theorem.

Comment: So,there is not a definite rule?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. For one curve/surface, there are many different ways to parametrize it and they are all valid. We use different parametrization for different purposes.

Comment: For example,can we trace an ellipse in both clockwise and counter-clockwise direction?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one curve/surface, we can parametrize it differently. For example, consider an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. It can be parametrized as $\langle a\cos(t),b\sin(t)\rangle$, or as $\langle a\cos(t),-b\sin(t)\rangle$. You can verify that the first parametrization is counter-clockwise, and the second one is clockwise.

There is no *principle*, per se, in choosing parametrization as long as it is correct. However, sometimes we may want to choose a specific type of parametrization for various reasons. One simple example is the **arc-length parametrization**. If you parametrize a curve using an arc-length parametrization, the speed (the norm of velocity) will always equal to $1$, which makes life a bit easier in some cases. Another example is that, in order to use some theorems (such as Stoke's Theorem), the theorems require that the curve is parametrized in counter-clockwise direction.